# How to draw 2 sides separate arrows by plt.arrow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw 2 opposite sides arrows from 2 points with plt like this

[image: 2 separate arrows]

Right now I can draw 2 opposite sides arrows but one on top of other like this

[image]

I know that the code to draw is

```
plt.arrow(x_start, y_start, x_length, y_length)
```

But don't know how to draw 2 separate arrows like that. Any idea to calculate the offset, (x, y) coordinate for starting point of those 2 arrows ?

Comment: are you asking how to compute the offsets?

Comment: yup, I think I'm gonna edit it clarify ít

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have your x-values and y-values as defined below (x_length is maybe misleading here):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_start = 0.2
x_delta = 0.7
y_start = 0.2
y_delta = 0.4
```

Based on `x_delta` and `y_delta` you can calculate a normalized (length=1) orthogonal vector (orthogonal to your arrow):

```
orth_vector = np.array([y_delta, -x_delta])
orth_normalized = orth_vector/np.linalg.norm(orth_vector)
```

By the help of the orthogonal vector you can shift your arrow in any direction keeping it parallel to the original arrow. E.g., using `offset=0.1` in the example below, the arrow will be shifted, so that is has a distance of `0.1`

```
offset = 0.1
x_start_shift = x_start + offset * orth_normalized[0]
y_start_shift = y_start + offset * orth_normalized[1]
```

Plotting everything show the shifted arrow alongside with the orignal arrow (Note: you can keep the deltas, you only need to shift the starting points):

```
plt.scatter(x_start, y_start)
plt.scatter(x_start + x_delta, y_start + y_delta)
plt.arrow(x_start,y_start,x_delta,y_delta)
plt.arrow(x_start_shift,y_start_shift,x_delta,y_delta)
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.xlim(0,1)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Awesome. I did it. Thank you very much.